# Can't decode a cyrillic string in python

Tags: python, encoding

I have an encoded file with strings like

```
b'1'    b'\xca\xee\xef\xe5\xe9\xf1\xea' b'1'    b'ADMIN'    b'2013-07-08 00:21:55'  
b'2'    b'\xd7\xe5\xeb\xff\xe1\xe8\xed\xf1\xea' b'1'    b'ADMIN'    b'2013-07-08 00:22:05'
```

How should I decode it? I tried to use codecs, decode/encode cp1251, but it didn't work.

`file -bi` says charset=us-ascii

There should be a string in cyrillic(cp1251) actually

python 2.7

The output:

```
>>> w=r'\xd7\xe5\xe\xff\xe1\xe8\xed\xf1\xea'
>>> w='\xd7\xe5\xe\xff\xe1\xe8\xed\xf1\xea'
ValueError: invalid \x escape
>>> w=r'\xd7\xe5\xe\xff\xe1\xe8\xed\xf1\xea'
>>> w.decode('raw_unicode_escape')
u'\\xd7\\xe5\\xe\\xff\\xe1\\xe8\\xed\\xf1\\xea'
>>> w.decode('utf-8')
u'\\xd7\\xe5\\xe\\xff\\xe1\\xe8\\xed\\xf1\\xea'
>>> unicode(w)
u'\\xd7\\xe5\\xe\\xff\\xe1\\xe8\\xed\\xf1\\xea'
>>> unicode(w, 'utf-8')
u'\\xd7\\xe5\\xe\\xff\\xe1\\xe8\\xed\\xf1\\xea'
```

I did everything: decode("utf-8"), used unicode and so, but nothing changes. Every time I get the same set of bytes.

Comment: "it didn't work" - what happened? What result did you get? Crazy text? Encoding error? Something else?

Comment: I get the same string, it simply doesn't change, I can't even get it as unicode characters starting with \u.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Show us what happens - copy-paste an interpreter transcript for us to see.

Comment: added. I used to work with encodings (cyr<->utf) previously, it was fine, but now I'm stuck;(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is you are missing a `b` after the 3rd `\x` escape in your `w` variable when it says invalid escape.

```
>>> w = '\xd7\xe5\xeb\xff\xe1\xe8\xed\xf1\xea'
>>> w.decode('cp1251')
u'\u0427\u0435\u043b\u044f\u0431\u0438\u043d\u0441\u043a'
```

Comment: thanks! this works :     print w.decode('cp1251').encode('utf-8')=> Челябинск